# Insufficient privilege when create dynamic table in stored procedure while in PL/SQL block table has been created

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

When i execute stored procedure which contain `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` along with `create table` statement inside the stored procedure then getting error while execute this Stored Proc.
Here is the Stored proc-

```
create or replace sp_exec
 as
 .......
 v_mth date;
 .......
begin
 select to_char(add_months(current_DATE, -1), 'MON_YY') INTO v_mth FROM dual;
  execute immediate 'create table tbl_mon_' ||v_mth|| ' as select ............... from ..... ';
end;
```

When I try to execute this Stored proc then getting error "**Insufficient Privilege**" at 2nd last line using this code to execute Stored Proc.

```
 begin
  sp_exec;
 end;
```

then getting error which mentioned below:-

```
 ORA-01031: Insufficient privilege
 ORA-06512: at sp_exec line 11  --here line 11 mention for Execute immediate
 ORA-06512: at line 2         -- here mention for sp_exec in the PLSQL block
```

I am working in the user schema itself so I've all types of privileges even `CREATE TABLE` statement also. When i run outside the stored procedure (**PL/SQL** block) then dynamic table have been created.

Comment: Creating a monthly table dynamically seems to be a very poor design.

Comment: For example materialized view or partitioning

Comment: @md wasi i think probable you need `GRANT` access for that

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you acquired the `create table` privilege via role. It won't work in named PL/SQL procedures, which means that you'll have to grant it directly to user.

Comment: Do you have a privilege to select from a table which is source for your dynamically created table? Code you posted suggests that you are selecting `from v_mth`, where ˙`v_mth` is a **date**; you can't select from a table whose name is 01-JUN-19, can you?

Comment: OK, but your code says: `as select ............... from '|| v_mth ||' ..... '`. This `v_mth` is equal to 01-JUN-19 (or whichever format TO_DATE in your database returns by default). That's an invalid table name. Unless, of course, you oversimplified code you posted. Try to create a simple example we'll be able to reproduce.